# .dat files can't be played in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I have installed Ubuntu `11.04`.When I tried to play `.dat` files in `vlc media player`,It showed error and the file could not played.Can someone tell me how to play `.dat` files in Ubuntu?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: [`.dat`](http://filext.com/file-extension/DAT) files may not necessarily contain media (music, video), so VLC might not be able to play them. Are you sure it contains media?

Comment: Yes.It has.When I played the same file in Windows Xp with the help of vlc media player it played the file without any errors.So how to play that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe checking these two links would help:

http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/open-source/36799-how-play-vcd-dat-files-ubuntu.html

http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/05/playing-dat-media-file-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

.dat are"fata files", often used as temporary storage by download managers, among many other uses. As such, the content of dat files isn't standarized to be of one or another format. vlc will happily consume any dat files containing multimedia data in any of the myriad of formats it can read, but, depending on their origin, some files will simply contain data that's not readable by vlc.

If your file does indeed contain multimedia data, and does happen to come from a download manager, an incomplete download may be the culprit. If the first few bytes of the file are missing, vlc will be unable to identify the file format, and refuse to play it. Just to make sure, you could give it a shot with mplayer.

Answer (score -2):

.dat files cant be played nor in VLC neither in windows media player because show time(time to play  video) content will not be stored for dat files. So you can use power DVD player to file such kind of files.

Comment: How about no? `.dat` is just a generic ending to specify "data" files. File-endings are just smoke and mirrors and you cannot know what's really in there unless you look into it.